# To get variation product minimum price

Tags: wordpress-theming

How can I code the apply_filter for this add_filter function to getting woocommerce products variation minimum price in wordpress theme file? This is my add_filter function coding for getting variation minimum price.

add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'conditional_payment_gateways', 10, 1);
function conditional_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {

```
foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    // Get the WC_Product object
    $product = wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']);
    // Only for variable products
    if($product->is_type('variable')){
        // Get the Variation "min" price
        $variation_min_price = $product->get_variation_price('min');
        // If the product category match with the variation 'min" price
        if( has_term( $variation_min_price, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ){
            // Cash on delivery (cod) payment gateway
            unset($available_gateways['cod']); // unset 'cod'
            break; // stop the loop
        }
    }
}
return $available_gateways;
}
```